# Adb framebuffer scale screen

Tags: android, adb, screenshot, framebuffer

I'm trying to implement app to transfer android screen from device to pc using adb. Is there exist any way to receive scaled image from adb using framebuffer command? Or maybe there exist some other way?

Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same problem, grabbing a 1920x1080x32bpp takes ~2 seconds while grabbing 1280x720x32bpp takes ~0.5sec, being able to receive a reduced size image via USB would solve the problem...